# In a dockerfile, how to delete a directory and its contents from docker image? (windows)

Tags: windows, powershell, docker, dockerfile, docker-build

I'm using the `python:3.6.5-windowsservercore` base image.

`COPY . /app` copies the build context into `C:\app`. This includes certain secret keys required for building the project.

After running the build, I want to delete keys folder (C:\app\keys), for this I use:

```
RUN powershell.exe Remove-Item -Path C:\app\keys -Force
```

Note - I have also tried each of following alternatives:

```
RUN Remove-Item -Path C:\app\keys -Force
RUN RD /S /Q C:\app\keys
```

This gives me following error:

```
Step 10/14 : RUN powershell.exe Remove-Item -Path C:\app\keys -Force
 ---> Running in 4e22124332b1
Remove-Item : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
At line:1 char:1
+ Remove-Item -Path C:\app\keys -Force
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Remove-Item], NullReferenceEx
   ception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.NullReferenceException,Microsoft.PowerShe
   ll.Commands.RemoveItemCommand

The command 'powershell -Command $ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'; $ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue'; powershell.exe Remove-Item -Path C:\app\keys -Force' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

What is the way to delete directory inside the image?

Comment: Just making sure, in case it has any effect on the parsing of the cmdlet and parameters Powershell is given, because I can see it in the error output, but I usually see the docker command contain the `-Command` parameter for `powershell.exe`. Like this, `RUN powershell.exe -Command Remove-Item -Path "C:\app\keys" -Force`. Apologies if you've already tried this. If you have already ran something like, `SHELL ["powershell", "-Command", "$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'; $ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue';"]` first, you only need to run `RUN Remove-Item -Path C:\app\keys -Force`.

Comment: 1. I just tried using -Command; I get the same error; 2. No I have not run command similar to SHELL

Comment: I confirm, you just need to add ```RUN Remove-Item -Path C:\app\keys -Force``` in your dockerfile. you can find some help maybe here: https://github.com/Drylm/rmq-win/blob/master/Dockerfile.3.7.7

Comment: No, it's the same error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution:

```
RUN Remove-Item -Path C:\app\keys -Force -Recurse
```

There are 2 aspects to resolve this.

1. Based on your base image, what is your default shell? Bash or powershell? In my case it was powershell, so there is no need to mention powershell.exe at the beginning of the command.
2. The original command was incorrect `RUN Remove-Item -Path C:\app\keys -Force` because the folder had sub-folders and files. So you have to mention `-Recurse`

Comment: `-Recurse` is buggy and won't work for large trees.